# ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined. - When i run jest debug on Chrome DevTools

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, jestjs

When i run "node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand" to debug my jest test the "const mongoose = require('mongoose')" returns a reference error. How to fix this ?

my test code is:

```
const {getDocuments} = require('./handleDatabase');
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const userSchema = require('../schemas/user');
const UserModelTest = mongoose.model('userTest', userSchema);

test('Should return a array of documents', async() => {
  debugger;                    
  const dbConfig = require('../../bin/dbConfig');
  await dbConfig(27017, 'test');  
  const query = {};            
  const documents = await getDocuments(query, UserModelTest);
  expect(documents).toEqual(expect.not.objectContaining({status: false}));

})
```

My test runs very well, the unique problem that i found was the reference error when i try to import mongoose and my mongooseSchema.

full error msg:

"ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined
    at eval (eval at Object..test (/home/sergipesecurity/Desktop/projetoBetBom/src/services/getDocuments.test.js:7:2), :1:1)
    at Object..test (/home/sergipesecurity/Desktop/projetoBetBom/src/services/getDocuments.test.js:7:2)
    at Object.asyncJestTest (/home/sergipesecurity/Desktop/projetoBetBom/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
    at resolve (/home/sergipesecurity/Desktop/projetoBetBom/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
    at new Promise ()
    at mapper (/home/sergipesecurity/Desktop/projetoBetBom/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
    at promise.then (/home/sergipesecurity/Desktop/projetoBetBom/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41)"

Comment: Can you please add the full error message?

Comment: Hi Peter, i edited the post, i put the full error message in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After makes more tests and put the debugger key in other places in my code, i saw this error in others variables. it should be a perfomance feature.

I put debugger key one line after `const mongoose = require('mongoose')` and works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you properly import mongoose on getDocuments.test.js.
make sure you have

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

on getDocuments file.

If possible could you please provide the getDocuments file also.

Comment: Hello Badri :)
after makes more tests and put the debugger key in other places in my code, i saw this error in others variables. it should be a perfomance feature. i will finish this question. Thanks my friend.

Comment: I put debugger key one line after const mongoose = require('mongoose') and works.